# Construct custom template in C++ class

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor

I have a custom template which I would like to initialise in my C++ class. I would like to directly set the size of it.

Template class, vector3d.hh

```
template <typename T>
class vector3d {
public:
vector3d(size_t d1=0, size_t d2=0, size_t d3=0, T const & t=T()) :
    d1(d1), d2(d2), d3(d3), data(d1*d2*d3, t){}

T & operator()(size_t i, size_t j, size_t k) {
    return data[i*d2*d3 + j*d3 + k];
}

T const & operator()(size_t i, size_t j, size_t k) const {
    return data[i*d2*d3 + j*d3 + k];
}

private:
    size_t d1,d2,d3;
    std::vector<T> data;
};
```

Class in which I wouldl like to initialise my template variable:

```
#include "vector3d.hh"
class foo{
 public:
  vector3d<int> testvector(1000,2000,3000);
}
```

But trying to compile this code generates the following error pointing at my initialised vector3d:

> error: expected identifier before numeric constant

I know this is not how we are meant to construct such things in classes. What is the proper error free for doing this? Assume I cannot use the new C++11 standard.

Comment: You should initialize `testvector` in `foo`'s constructor, just the same way as you initialize `data` in `vector3d`'s constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Assume I cannot use the new C++11 standard" - in which case, you can't initialise non-static members in their declarations. You'll have to do it in the constructor:

```
vector3d<int> testvector;
foo() : testvector(1000,2000,3000) {}
```

In modern C++, you can initialise it there, but not using `()`. In-class initialisation can only use `=` or `{}`:

```
vector3d<int> testvector{1000,2000,3000};
```